# Processing - Ellipse is covering text

Tags: processing

In the below image, I would like to have the score as text within the green ellipse. However, the ellipse is being drawn over the text, regardless of the order of the `ellipse()` and `text()` functions in the loop. Can anyone suggest why? My `draw` loop is shown below.

[image: This is what it looks like]

```java
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PFont;

public void drawHUD(PApplet marker, Clock time, int score)
{
    PFont font = marker.createFont("Impact", 25, true);
    marker.textFont(font);
    marker.ellipseMode(CENTER);
    fill(25, 100, 25);
    marker.ellipse(50, marker.height - 50, 75, 50);
    marker.noFill();
    marker.text("Score: ", 25, marker.height - 100);
    marker.text(score, 50, marker.height - 50);
    marker.text("Seconds left: ", marker.width - 175, marker.height - 100);
    marker.text(time.toString(), marker.width - 125, marker.height - 50);
}
```

Comment: Can you include your imports? what are `PApplet` and `PFont` and etc ?

Comment: added the imports, they are just standard processing imports

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot showing what's going on? Or better yet, can you please post a [mcve] that we can actually run?

Comment: @alfasin Please note that this is a [tag:processing] question, and [Processing != Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321127/processing-java). The `PApplet` and `PFont` classes are internal Processing classes.

Comment: I added a picture explaining whats showing up

Comment: where is `score` defined ? Arn't you painting black `marker.text(score, 50, marker.height - 50);` on black eclipse ?

Comment: Why do you directly call `fill()` instead of `marker.fill()`? That's pretty suspicious. Do you have two classes that extend `PApplet`?

Comment: I pass in a marker, yes I have more than one class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the ellipsemode. It got rid of the center ellipse, but it got the text to the front.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `marker.noFill();` with `marker.fill(255);`. I don't believe `noFill()` works for text, and I have a feeling the text is being drawn above the ellipse, but is just the same colour as the ellipse so can't be seen.